# TWO instances of my android app being installed AT ONCE! What would cause this?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, manifest

I am new to android and I am having a minor problem installing the app.
When installing two instances appear on my device,

One instance goes to MainActivity (as it should) the other goes directly to the nWiFiScans Activity when clicked.

i know its a problem in my manifest, but i am just not sure how to properly declare a new activity in my manifest.

Any advice/help/angry comment are welcome....

The following is my

## **AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.surveyappv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.surveyappv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.surveyappv2.nWiFiScans"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: you have 1 app, but 2 launchers, hence 2 icons ...

Comment: Also, you **should** always start your class names with an uppercase, and it's a good practice to end activities with "Activity"

Comment: Upvoted: Useful question, demonstrated effort, sufficient and not overly abundant information. Good!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the `intent-filter` from the non-primary activity in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is what causes a launcher icon for the activity to appear.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!
Its small things like this that i am missing in my knowledge as a beginner.

THANK YOU! THANK YOU!

Ill come back and upvote you when i have enough rep points!